# gradle can not resolve any dependency for configuration: classpath

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

all my projects using gradle builder has this error. gradle can not sync and none of the dependencies resolve.
this is the error:
Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.7.1/gradle-6.7.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> Could not find android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/android/arch/navigation/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin/2.3.0/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin-2.3.0.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/navigation/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin/2.3.0/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin-2.3.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/android/arch/navigation/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin/2.3.0/navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin-2.3.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :
> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

this is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.7.1'
    classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0'

}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

and this is my :app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jartest2"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3.0"
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime:$nav_version"
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'}
```

and this is the log file:

```
INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2020-12-10 05:19:12,205 [47703891]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:12,596 [47704282]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=JarTest2, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=D:\computer\Java\IdeaProjects\JarTest2)JavacSettings took 16 ms 2020-12-10 05:19:12,706 [47704392]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:22,712 [47714398]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:23,226 [47714912]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:24,230 [47715916]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:24,746 [47716432]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:25,754 [47717440]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:26,263 [47717949]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:26,779 [47718465]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:27,294 [47718980]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:27,810 [47719496]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:28,326 [47720012]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:28,838 [47720524]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:29,344 [47721030]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:29,846 [47721532]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:30,354 [47722040]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:30,870 [47722556]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:31,385 [47723071]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:31,901 [47723587]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:31,932 [47723618]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [D:/computer/Java/IdeaProjects/JarTest2] resolution task started` 2020-12-10 05:19:32,010 [47723696]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_72  2020-12-10 05:19:32,010 [47723696]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_72  2020-12-10 05:19:32,042 [47723728]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.studio.tooling contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files(['C:\\\\Program Files\\\\JetBrains\\\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\JetBrains\\\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3\\\\plugins\\\\android\\\\lib\\\\android.jar', 'C:\\\\Program Files\\\\JetBrains\\\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3\\\\lib\\\\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.0.jar'])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin\n}\n"  2020-12-10 05:19:32,057 [47723743]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.sync.active=true -Didea.resolveSourceSetDependencies=true -Porg.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.cid=47899959731139 --init-script C:\Users\M.H\AppData\Local\Temp\sync.studio.tooling11867.gradle -Djava.awt.headless=true --stacktrace -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=10.4.0.203.5981.155 -Pandroid.injected.build.model.disable.src.download=true -Pidea.gradle.do.not.build.tasks=false --init-script C:\Users\M.H\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit5.gradle  2020-12-10 05:19:32,409 [47724095]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:32,925 [47724611]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:42,652 [47734338]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error  org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip'.
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:78)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.throwFailure(ProviderConnection.java:231)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:219)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runPhasedAction(ProviderConnection.java:179)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:245)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.run(PhasedActionAwareConsumerConnection.java:56)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:62)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultPhasedBuildActionExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:67)
... 6 more Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1710)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2102)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.serialization.PayloadSerializer.deserialize(PayloadSerializer.java:76)
... 19 more 2020-12-10 05:19:42,663 [47734349]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_72  2020-12-10 05:19:42,665 [47734351]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] IllegalStateException loading gradle script templates: Unable to get Gradle home directory  2020-12-10 05:19:42,668 [47734354]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Cannot find valid gradle home for null with version = null, script models cannot be saved  2020-12-10 05:19:42,669 [47734355]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [D:/computer/Java/IdeaProjects/JarTest2] resolution task executed in 10737 ms.  2020-12-10 05:19:42,961 [47734647]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 2020-12-10 05:19:43,067 [47734753]   INFO - ge.ExternalProjectsDataStorage - Save external projects data in 46 ms  2020-12-10 05:19:43,462 [47735148]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:43,963 [47735649]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:44,467 [47736153]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:44,983 [47736669]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:45,487 [47737173]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:45,992 [47737678]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:46,487 [47738173]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:47,518 [47739204]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:52,052 [47743738]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:55,073 [47746759]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:55,588 [47747274]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:56,104 [47747790]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:56,620 [47748306]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:57,128 [47748814]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:19:57,630 [47749316]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:02,671 [47754357]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:03,678 [47755364]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:04,175 [47755861]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:09,781 [47761467]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:10,278 [47761964]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:10,778 [47762464]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:11,282 [47762968]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:12,282 [47763968]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:12,785 [47764471]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:13,287 [47764973]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:13,787 [47765473]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:14,291 [47765977]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:14,806 [47766492]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:15,322 [47767008]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:15,822 [47767508]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:16,338 [47768024]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:16,853 [47768539]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:17,360 [47769046]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:17,861 [47769547]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:19,365 [47771051]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:19,881 [47771567]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:21,420 [47773106]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:21,921 [47773607]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:22,421 [47774107]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:22,921 [47774607]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:23,418 [47775104]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:23,780 [47775466]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appLangManager took 16 ms  2020-12-10 05:20:23,921 [47775607]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:28,929 [47780615]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:56,843 [47808529]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:20:57,358 [47809044]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:21:05,930 [47817616]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:21:06,430 [47818116]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found  2020-12-10 05:22:26,483 [47898169]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found
```

I check the internet connection. it works fine. after I use proxy but still have this error. I update my intellij to 11.0.9 and java to 10 but do not help. I check the JAVA_HOME path, it has defined correctly. I delete .gradle folder in my user home and invalidate caches and restart and build the project again but it also can not help.
now I'm using windows 10, intellij IDEA 11.0.9 and jdk 1.8. any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching I found the problem was the proxy. I changed the proxy server and gradle worked correctly!